# Select sequence of next siblings in Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have the following html to scrap

```
<h2>
  <span id="title">Title</span>
</h2>
<p>Content 1</p>
<p>Content 2</p>
<p>Content 3</p>
<p>Content 4</p>
<h2>Some other header</h2>
<p>Do not want this content</p>
```

What I want to select is a series of 4 `<p>` tags after the title, and ignore everything else as soon as a non `<p>` tag is encountered.

So far my xpath is `//h2[span[@id='title']]/following-sibling::p`, but this also includes unwanted

tags.

I also tried the preceding-sibling approach with no luck `//p[preceding-sibling::h2[span[@id='title']]]`. The extra `<p>` tag is still included.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this xpath :

`//p[preceding-sibling::h2[1][./span[@id = 'title']]]`

What does this xpath do :
It searches for `p` elements which have `h2` elements as preceding siblings but on one condition - only if their first preceding-sibling `h2` has a child called `span` with attribute `id` that equals `title`

Why it filtered `<p>Do not want this content</p>` ? :
Because this `p`'s preceding `h2`s when listed appear in the order :

`<h2>Some other header</h2>`

`<h2>
  <span id="title">Title</span>
</h2>`

hence `h2[1][./span[@id = 'title']]` turns out to be false, and consequently this `p` is not returned.

The result on an example xml :

```
<root>
<h2>
  <span id="title">Title</span>
</h2>
<p>Content 1</p>
<p>Content 2</p>
<p>Content 3</p>
<p>Content 4</p>
<h2>Some other header</h2>
<p>Do not want this content</p>
<p>Do not want this content too</p>
</root>
```

is :

```
'<p>Content 1</p>'
'<p>Content 2</p>'
'<p>Content 3</p>'
'<p>Content 4</p>'
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you using BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup =  BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
p_list = []
for i in soup.find('span' ,{'id':'title'}).parent.next_siblings:
    if i.name=='p':
        p_list.append(i)
print p_list
```

Comment: Thanks CK. This is useful for more complex rules.