# How to scrape a table with sub-rows that do not belong to any hierarchy?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

| Technology (A) | 2G bands (A) | 2G bands (B) | 3G bands (A) | 3G bands (B) | 4G bands (A) | 4G bands (B) | 5G bands (A) | 5G bands (B) | 5G bands (C) | Speed (A) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text | text |

### How to get a structured output, as mentioned above, from the following html table?

```
<table cellspacing="0">

    <tr class="tr-hover">
    <th rowspan="15" scope="row">Network</th>
    <td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">Technology</a></td>
    <td class="nfo"><a href="#" class="link-network-detail" data-spec="nettech">GSM / CDMA / HSPA / EVDO / LTE / 5G</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-toggle">
    <td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">2G bands</a></td>
    <td class="nfo" data-spec="net2g">GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 - SIM 1 & SIM 2 (dual-SIM)</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="tr-toggle" data-spec-optional>
    <td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="nfo">CDMA 800 / 1900 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-toggle">
    <td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">3G bands</a></td>
    <td class="nfo" data-spec="net3g">HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1700(AWS) / 1900 / 2100 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-toggle" data-spec-optional>
    <td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="nfo">CDMA2000 1xEV-DO </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-toggle">
    <td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">4G bands</a></td>
    <td class="nfo" data-spec="net4g">1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 46, 48, 66 - A2643, A2644, A2645</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-toggle" data-spec-optional>
    <td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="nfo">1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 34, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 46, 48, 66, 71 - A2484, A2641</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-toggle">
    <td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">5G bands</a></td>
    <td class="nfo" data-spec="net5g">1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 20, 25, 28, 30, 38, 40, 41, 48, 66, 77, 78, 79 SA/NSA/Sub6 - A2643, A2644</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-toggle" data-spec-optional>
    <td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="nfo">1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 20, 25, 28, 29, 30, 38, 40, 41, 48, 66, 71, 78, 79, 258, 260, 261 SA/NSA/Sub6/mmWave - A2484</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-toggle" data-spec-optional>
    <td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="nfo">1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 20, 25, 28, 29, 30, 38, 40, 41, 48, 66, 71, 77, 78, 79 SA/NSA/Sub6 - A2641</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-toggle">
    <td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=3g">Speed</a></td>
    <td class="nfo" data-spec="speed">HSPA 42.2/5.76 Mbps, LTE-A, 5G, EV-DO Rev.A 3.1 Mbps</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

**Dealing with these rows is my problem:** `<tr class="tr-toggle" data-spec-optional>`**.** They are not bound by any hierarchy.

---

This approaches have given me hope. But I was not successful in implementing it.

1. [how to select and extract texts between two elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957062/how-to-select-and-extract-texts-between-two-elements)
2. [Select sequence of next siblings in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646685/select-sequence-of-next-siblings-in-scrapy/43647765)

---

**Any kind of help would be really helpful!**

---

### Edit

At the very bottom *[LEVEL3]* I have to implement the solution. This is my structure of the spider and code:

***[Page LEVEL1]** Brands URL* https://www.gsmarena.com/makers.php3
***[Page LEVEL2]** All Devices URL* https://www.gsmarena.com/apple-phones-48.php
***[Page LEVEL3]** Detail Page URL* https://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_13_pro_max-11089.php

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
from gsm.items import GsmItem

class GsmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gsm'
    allowed_domains = ['gsmarena.com']
    start_urls = ['https://gsmarena.com/makers.php3']

    # LEVEL1 | all brands

    def parse(self, response):
        
        item = GsmItem()

        gsms = response.xpath('//div[@class="st-text"]/table//tr[3]//td[2]')
        for gsm in gsms:
            allbranddevicesurl = gsm.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
            brandname = gsm.xpath('.//a/text()').get()
            devicecount = gsm.xpath('.//span/text()').get()
            
            item['brandname'] = brandname
            item['devicecount'] = devicecount

            yield response.follow(allbranddevicesurl, callback=self.parse_allbranddevicesurl,
                                    meta= {'brandname': item,
                                           'devicecount': item})

    # LEVEL2 | all devices

    def parse_allbranddevicesurl(self, response):
        
        item = response.meta['brandname']       
        item = response.meta['devicecount'] 

        phones = response.xpath('//*[@id="review-body"]//li')
        for phone in phones:
            detailpageurl = phone.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
            
            item['detailpageurl'] = detailpageurl

            yield response.follow(detailpageurl,
                                    callback=self.parse_detailpage,
                                    meta= {'brandname': item,
                                           'devicecount': item,
                                           'detailpageurl': item,})

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="pages-next"]/@href').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_allbranddevicesurl,
                                    meta= {'brandname': item,
                                           'devicecount': item,
                                           'detailpageurl': item,})

    # LEVEL3 | Detailpage
    
    def parse_detailpage(self, response):
     
        item = response.meta['brandname']       
        item = response.meta['devicecount']
        item = response.meta['detailpageurl']

 
        for row in response.xpath('//tr[@class="tr-toggle"]'):
            if row.xpath('.//a'):
                ch = 'A'
                title1 = row.xpath('.//a/text()').get()
            else:
                ch = chr(ord(ch)+1)
            title = title1 + f' ({ch})'
            data = row.xpath('.//td[@class="nfo"]/text()').get()
            
            item['title'] = title
            item['data'] = data

        yield item
```

---

Comment: If you're handling all `class="tr-toggle"` rows, then it should get those just fine.  Right?  What problems are you having?

Comment: Right, I get all the text strings. But how do I get them in a structured way? As you can see, the first `class="tr-toggle"` comes with a header **4G bands** inside `<td>`. The second `<tr class="tr-toggle" data-spec-optional>` belongs to it. With the third `class="tr-toggle"` comes an absolutely new header **5G bands** with the corresponding sub-rows following... Thanks, @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'm sure it's not the best way but it works. If I'll think of another way then I'll edit the answer.

```py
In [1]: html="""<html>
   ...: <body>
   ...: <table cellspacing="0">
   ...: 
   ...:    <tr class="tr-toggle">
   ...:     <td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">4G bands</a></td>
   ...:     <td class="nfo" data-spec="net4g">1, 2, 3 - A2643</td>
   ...:     </tr>
   ...: 
   ...:     <tr class="tr-toggle" data-spec-optional>
   ...:     <td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
   ...:     <td class="nfo">1, 2, 3 - A2484</td>
   ...:     </tr>
   ...: 
   ...:     <tr class="tr-toggle">
   ...:     <td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">5G bands</a></td>
   ...:     <td class="nfo" data-spec="net5g">1, 2, 3 - A2643</td>
   ...:     </tr>
   ...: 
   ...:     <tr class="tr-toggle" data-spec-optional>
   ...:     <td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
   ...:     <td class="nfo">1, 2, 3 - A2484</td>
   ...:     </tr>
   ...: 
   ...:     <tr class="tr-toggle" data-spec-optional>
   ...:     <td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
   ...:     <td class="nfo">1, 2, 3 - A2641</td>
   ...:     </tr>
   ...:     
   ...: </table>
   ...: </body>
   ...: </html>"""

In [2]: from scrapy import Selector

In [3]: response = Selector(text=html)

In [4]: for row in response.xpath('//tr[@class="tr-toggle"]'):
   ...:     if row.xpath('.//a'):
   ...:         ch = 'A'
   ...:         title1 = row.xpath('.//a/text()').get()
   ...:     else:
   ...:         ch = chr(ord(ch)+1)
   ...:     title = title1 + f' ({ch})'
   ...:     data = row.xpath('.//td[@class="nfo"]/text()').get()
   ...:     print(f'\"{title}\" : \"{data}\"')
   ...:
"4G bands (A)" : "1, 2, 3 - A2643"
"4G bands (B)" : "1, 2, 3 - A2484"
"5G bands (A)" : "1, 2, 3 - A2643"
"5G bands (B)" : "1, 2, 3 - A2484"
"5G bands (C)" : "1, 2, 3 - A2641"
```

Comment: I tried it with the url you provided and it is working fine. Did you copy the code correctly?

Comment: Can you please write that line of code?

Comment: I'm sure it's my implementation and not your solution. Now I no longer get an error. I get `'title': 'Speed (A)'` as datapoint and `'data': 'HSPA 42.2/5.76 Mbps, LTE-A, EV-DO Rev.A 3.1 Mbps, 5G'`. I think I am getting closer to the goal thanks to @SuperUser. I just need to get your approach right. I'm testing it right now.

Comment: Added all my code to the question. In LEVEL3 (at the bottom) I try to apply your solution to the whole table...

Comment: @Alexander I can fix it, but I got `too many request`. I'll update you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by @SuperUser's answer of using the ordinal value to increment the count. You can obtain the headers and values using xpath and then combine them to form the final dictionary

```py
import re

titles = response.xpath("//tr[@class='tr-toggle']/td[@class='ttl']/descendant-or-self::*/text()").getall()

for i, title in enumerate(titles):
    if title.strip() == '':
        prev_letter = re.search(r"\((.)\)$", titles[i-1]).group(1)
        new_title = f"{titles[i-1][:-4]} ({chr(ord(prev_letter) + 1)})"
        titles[i] = new_title
    else:
        titles[i] = f"{title} (A)"

values = response.xpath("//tr[@class='tr-toggle']/td[@class='nfo']/text()").getall()

results = {}
for title, value in zip(titles, values):
    results[title] = value
```

When you print the results dictionary you obtain the below

```py
{'4G bands (A)': '1, 2, 3 - A2643',
 '4G bands (B)': '1, 2, 3 - A2484',
 '5G bands (A)': '1, 2, 3 - A2643',
 '5G bands (B)': '1, 2, 3 - A2484',
 '5G bands (C)': '1, 2, 3 - A2641'}
```